# Why argv[] is declared as const?

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, why argv[] is declared as const:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) { }
```

Comment: Because that's how it's supposed to be in C too. :)

Comment: Note that it is not strictly conforming C if you declare it const.

Comment: I have a feeling that it is simply convention.  It marks the arguments as non-modifiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `const` denotes that the value (`char *`) is immutable, which arguments are.

Once program arguments are handed off to a program, their values should not be modifiable.

Think of this array as an *array of `const char *`'s*, which in turn, is an array of `char`s.

So, say you passed the string "hello world" to your program as arguments, `argv` would look like this:

```
{{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}, {'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '\0'}}
```

Comment: Program arguments are required to be modifiable in a C program - _"The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last stored values between program startup and program termination"_

Comment: This answer is plainly wrong.  As @D.Shawley has pointed out, the C99 standard states explicitly that the arguments are modifiable (section 5.1.2.2.1 last bullet point).  The fact that the template created by Xcode uses `const` is erroneous.  Either that or the OS X executable environment does not comply with C99.

Answer (score 0):

Because it makes writing the shell/program launcher/etc simpler while not making most programs much more complicated.

And the creators of 'C' were thinking ahead to make OS writers jobs easier - especially their own!

Comment: There was no `const` keyword in C when it was created.  By the way, as D.Shawley has pointed out, C99 specifically states that the strings pointed to by argv are modifiable by the program.