# How do you concatenate .txt on the end of user input, in C?

Tags: python, c, io

I am trying to retrieve user input, and find out whether or not they have added ".txt" onto the end of their input. If they have, do nothing, if not - do something.

Here is some code I have so far: (argv[3]and[4] being the inputs of the user):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

        if (strlen(argv[3]) > 4){
            usernames = strcpy(argv[2], ".txt");
        }
        if (strlen(argv[4]) > 4){
            passwords = strcpy(argv[3], ".txt");
        }
}
```

I have already mastered it in Python, I just cannot convert it into C programming. Here is my Python version working:

```
#Ask user for a file name
while True:
        inp = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
        if len(inp) > 0:
                break
        else:
                print "No file name givin, please try again"
#Check if file name has ".txt" on the end
if inp[-4:] != ".txt":
        inp = str(inp)+".txt"
```

Comment: Don't overlook the declaration `int main(int argc, const char * argv[])` which means that strings pointed to by `argv` cannot be.... what?

Comment: @WeatherVane: You're allowed to write to `argv`. It's not `const`.

Comment: @EOF uh - OK but still unwise.

Comment: @WeatherVane: C11 draft standard, section `5.1.2.2.1 Program startup`: `The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.` Says nothing about "unwise".

Comment: @EOF this SO question tackles it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425330/why-argv-is-declared-as-const?rq=1

Comment: @WeatherVane: And the accepted answer is dead wrong in many ways, as the commenters point out below it. Your point?

Comment: My point is that it would be unwise to concatenate ".txt" onto an `argv[]` passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C and python are very different languages - one of the biggest difference is the need to statically declare variables. In your code, the variables `usernames` and `passwords` have to be declared and of the correct type to allow assignment. Here's some code which adds ".txt" to usernames or passwords based on the conditions in your code.

```
#include "stdio.h"   /* Allows us to call printf */
#include "string.h"  /* Allows us to use string functions (strlen, strcmp, ctrcpy) */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  size_t SIZE = 100;
  char usernames[SIZE], passwords[SIZE]; /* Create char arrays to store our inputs */

  printf("O usernames: %s, O passwords %s\n", argv[2], argv[3]); /* Print input */

  if (strlen(argv[3]) > 4) {
    strcpy(usernames, argv[2]); /* Copy argv[2] to usernames */
    if (strcmp(usernames + strlen(usernames) - 4, ".txt") )
      strcat(usernames, ".txt");
  }

  if (strlen(argv[4]) > 4) {
    strcpy(passwords, argv[3]); /* Copy argv[3] to passwords */
    if (strcmp(passwords + strlen(passwords) - 4, ".txt") )
      strcat(passwords, ".txt");
  }

  printf("U usernames: %s, U passwords %s\n", usernames, passwords); /* Print output */
  return 0;
}
```

We make use of `strcpy` to copy the char array from `argv` to `usernames`. We also use `strcmp` to check if the last 4 characters are `.txt`. `strcmp` in my code uses some pointer math to ensure we check the last 4 characters. We make the same checks for `passwords` as well.

### Sample input:

```
./a.out 1 uname upass foobar
```

### Sample output:

```
O usernames: uname, O passwords upass.txt
U usernames: uname.txt, U passwords upass.txt
```

Comment: Good answer, but there are 2 things that this code should check:  1) That the user input is not longer than `SIZE - 1` characters so you don't overflow your string buffers.  2)  That appending ".txt" to the end doesn't overflow the string buffers.

Comment: @indiv, agreed - I wanted to keep it simple and not get into the nitty-gritties of C. One more thing to mention is of course the string methods should be replaced with their `n` variants (strncmp, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int SIZE = 100;
    char string[SIZE];
    scanf("%s", string);
    if(!strcmp(&(string[strlen(string)-4]), ".txt"))
        //do something

return 0;
```

}

## EDIT: all strings ends with ".txt" now

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    int SIZE = 100;
    char string[SIZE];
    scanf("%s", string);
    if(strcmp(&(string[strlen(string)-4]), ".txt"))
        strcat(string, ".txt");

    printf("%s\n", string); //all strings ends with ".txt" now
    return 0;
}
```